# Is it possible to replace the browser's URL without leaving or reloading the page using C# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to access the url of the browser even before the page is loaded and replace it.

I just do not want the user to be able to watch on which page s/he is landing.

I though of accessing the url in Page_Init, but I can't find out how.

Any thoughts or better - solutions?

EDITED:
I do not need to change (or remove) the server name in the URL, only the folder/file name.
So, if the original page location is of the form: `http://www.server.com/folder/file.aspx` I would like to change it to `http://www.server.com/misc/GeneralPage.aspx` or `http://www.server.com/`

Response.Redirect will not do. I would like to stay at the same page, but to change the URL.

Server.Transfer is the default solution with a helper pre landing file, but it is not good enough for me. I would like to stay in the same page, but to change the displayed URL.

---

Solution:

**There was an answer here involving HTML5 and one more solution direction, which I had in mind to investigate soon, but it is not here anymore (disappeared). If it was your answer, please write it once more. It was an important one.**

I gave here the best option found as my decision of action (for now, until I'll find a better solution), but I do not take credit for it (I do not mark it as an answer).
It is a detailed tested solution.

Comment: Are you looking for something other than `Response.Redirect("http://newurl.com");`?

Comment: what is the objective here? you can't hide the original URL because how else is the browser supposed to know where to go? i have a bad feeling this is somehow "security" related.

Comment: if you change the url on `init` the user will not see it until you actually perform a redirect...

Comment: Kirk Woll- other than that and other then Server.Transfer("...

Comment: cotton.m - In page_load and page_init the browser already knows where to go to, but I would like to change the display and the display only.

Comment: @Different111222, `Server.Transfer` does *not* modify the URL.

Comment: Xander- I would not like to redirect. I would like to get to the page without displaying the the url but some other string.

Comment: There is no need to do this. Why do you want to?

Comment: Kirk Woll- but it does redirect, and I would not like to redirect - just to change the display of the url, before even the page is loading.

Comment: cotton.m - I would not like the user to see the url of the page s/he is on.

Comment: @Different111222 either just use redirect and/or some sort of url-rewriting scheme. You still have not said why those won't work for you. But they are all you have available to you.

Comment: cotton.m - yes, it is about security. I'm building a simple website which I do not need much of security, but need some. Simple as it is, if the user do not know the page address, s/he cannot get to it directly. It will save me a lot of time and trouble.

Comment: @Different111222 Well it doesn't help security in any way but that's okay because you can't do it. Fix whatever the problem is in another way.

Comment: @Different111222, you said, "Simple as it is, if the user do not know the page address, s/he cannot get to it directly. It will save me a lot of time and trouble."   This strategy will *categorically not work*.  Full stop.  Abandon all hope, etc.  There is literally no way to provide a resource from a URL to a client and hide that URL from the client.  If you think about it, you'll realize why the whole idea is complete nonsense.   Your security simply *cannot* rely on whether the user knows the URL.  You'll have to authorize through one of the myriad other mechanisms at your disposal.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible due to browser security features. If the browser allowed programmers to display different URLs than what the user was actually on, then there would be a lot more people unknowingly  handing over their sensitive banking information to third parties.

The URL is supposed to identify the specific resource that was requested by a browser and returned by the server.

With that said, there are domain masking tricks you can use at the Domain Management level. One technique used by GoDaddy is to foward your domain with masking, this essentially loads your website in an iframe so that the original URL is preserved at the original domain with the new content served up in an iframe.

You could also use this technique yourself. When you return content to the browser, return an iframe with the src attribute pointing to the new content.

Still, as far as modifying the actual URL displayed, this is not possible, and I'm not sure why you would really even want to do this.

Comment: Thanks. I've wrote my decision of action as an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, you cannot change the entire URL in order to stop URL spoofing and thus phishing attacks.

You can, however, change any portion of the URL after the hash (#) sign. This portion of the URL is only available in client side javascript and can be used to store state information of the current page without reloading it. It is the `windows.location.hash` property.

Comment: Nick Whaley - Assuming the URL is of the form `http://server/folder/file.ext`, could I at least change the URL to be of the form `http://server/` so the user will know that the address is authentic, but will not know the actual folder and file location?

Comment: @Different111222, If the URL requested from the server is `http://server/folder/file.ext` then there is no hiding it. The client MUST know the destination if it is going to be requested from there.

Comment: Thanks. I've wrote my decision of action as an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving here my decision for action (temporal).
As soon as I'll decide on a better solution, I'll post it here with credit.

Although it is the solution I wished to avoid, it looks like it is the best there is for now.

After reading all answers and comments, the solution I decided on is to have an empty landing page and use Server.Transfer to the hidden file. I put the Server.Transfer in Page_Init.

The lading page `Lading.aspx` contains one line only:

```
<%@ CodeFile="Landing.aspx.cs" Inherits="Landing" %>
```

It's code behind `Landing.aspx.cs` contains:

```
using System;
public partial class Landing : System.Web.UI.Page
{protected void Page_Init(){Server.Transfer("~/Landing_Hidden.aspx");}}
```

The hidden page `Landing_Hidden.aspx` is a regular aspx page.

Many thanks to everyone with answers and comments.

I find that in phishing view mentioned here, there is no difference using this above solution other than changing the URL.

Comment: Why are you so worried about doing this? Do you work for some highly secretive defense agency? Have you also made sure that you're server can't be hacked and is locked down or is this just an attempt at security through obscurity?

Comment: jmort253- On the contrary, no secrecy at all. This is a way to avoid investing time in security which is not needed, but to some level. It is an intranet and I know my people and their abilities. Above that with regards to your comment, securing the server is someone else's mission and problem, not mine - I must admit she is a magician regarding network/servers security who saved us many times.

Answer (score 0):

var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");

you can use this code by creating java-script function and call it on clientclick event of a button

in place of bar.html
just change to any of your url e.g. index.html
and when you will click on button your output will be as follows
i.e. www.dotnetprofessional.in/bar.html or www.dotnetprofessional.in/index.html
without page getting post back or refresh

[reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)