# Redirect to different URL and show another URL(page in this URL Does Not Exist) in address bar in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I have a link that redirects to  **"/Certification/abc123.asp"**. Now what I want is page should redirect to some another page that is **"details.aspx?URL=/Certification/abc123.asp"** but URL in address bar should appear  **"/Certification/abc123.asp".** I have created Url rewriting rule in web.config.

Below is my code: in web.config

```
 <rule name="Redirects to Certifications" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*certifications*)"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/ERRoot/details.aspx?url={REQUEST_URI}"  appendQueryString="true"/>
    </rule>
```

By this I match my URL, if it contains "**certifications**" then it redirects to "**details.aspx**" page with Querystring key "**url**" that contains original URL. But my URL displays the page i have redirected to.

I want "/Certification/abc123.asp" to display in my address bar.

**Note:** There is no page like /Certification/abc123.asp. It is just a URL

Please help. Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: @mjwills My current page is "elist.asp" and i want it to redirect to "details.aspx" but address bar should display "/Certification/abc123.asp". The Link you suggested will not work in this case.

Comment: `elist.asp` should `Response.Redirect` to `/Certification/abc123.asp`. `/Certification/abc123.asp` should `Server.Transfer` to `details.aspx`.

Comment: @mjwills. /Certification/abc123.asp **this page does not exist**. It is just url and there are thousands of urls like this. So we have common template in detail.aspx. Based on querystring "url" we want to display data. I hope you understand my requirement.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10469692/9676724) might help

Comment: @AjayGupta Server.transfer will not work. Because I want to change URL from elist.asp to /Certification/abc123.asp. I think you have missed my **Note. /Certification/abc123.asp page Does Not Exist**. It is only URL I want to display to user and redirect to detail.aspx

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10467379/9676724) explains why this isn't possible if you don't want to create a hidden page.

Answer (score 0):

This code resolved my problem.

Global.asax:

```
private void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (System.IO.File.Exists(Request.PhysicalPath))
    {
        // Do nothing here, just serve the file
    }
    // If the file does not exist then
    else if (!System.IO.File.Exists(Request.PhysicalPath))
    {
        if (Request.ServerVariables["URL"].ToString() != "/")
        {
            // Get the URL requested by the user
            string sRequestedURL = Request.Path;

            string varurl = Request.ServerVariables["URL"].ToString().ToLower();
            string sTargetURL = "";

            if (varurl.Contains("/certifications/"))
            {
                sTargetURL = "~/Erroot/details.aspx?url=" + varurl;
            }

            if(sTargetURL!="")
            Context.RewritePath(sTargetURL, false);

        }
    }
}
```